# How can I make an element replace itself individually without knowing its ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this very poorly the first time. Sorry. Revised:

Each element will have an ID but I won't know what it will be beforehand. What I need is for hovering over each div to replace only its own list item, ie. hovering over `#1` makes `#1 .second` replace `#1 .first`, but doesn't make `#2 .second` replace `#2 .first`.

Here's what I have that affects both divs:

```
<div class="hover" id="1">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">First</li>
    <li class="second">Second</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="hover" id="2">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">First</li>
    <li class="second">Second</li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hover").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".second").show();
        $(".first").hide();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".second").hide();
        $(".first").show();
    });
});

.second {display:none;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L50bm2vp/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " it only replaces itself"?

Comment: it replaces itself with what?

Comment: nvm, figured it out, I think. For anybody else who is confused, he wants it so that when you hover over one of the span 1s, only that span 1 is turned into a span 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

target each `span1` class and show/hide its next `span2` class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div .span1").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).hide().next('.span2').show();

    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).show().next('.span2').hide();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your revised post you can do below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p2fLvp1L/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hover").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find(".second,.first").toggle();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".second,.first").toggle();
    });
});
```

> You were just missing to target the element on which you are doing
>   `hover` which can be done by targeting with `$(this)`

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hover").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find(".second").show();
        $(this).find(".first").hide();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".second").hide();
        $(this).find(".first").show();
    });
});
```